# Vue Checkboxes - Keep selected unless another checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using checkboxes to behave like radio buttons but the one behavior that I want to fix is the ability to keep the checkbox checked until the second one is checked (which will then uncheck the first one). I don't want the ability to deselect the checkbox by clicking on it again, just to hit the "none" checkbox to deselect the one below.

[image]

Referring to the image above, the label selects the checkbox as well. Once the checkbox is selected and is tapped on again, it goes back to the none checkbox on the left. Maybe radio buttons would be better, but I like checkboxes more. Here's the code:

```html
  <label :for="'none-'+product.id"
class="none addon_label"
:class="{'addon_selected': !selected}"
  >
    
  <input class=""
type="checkbox" 
:id="'none-'+product.id"
:true-value="false" 
:false-value="true"
:value="false"
v-model="selected"
checked
  />
  <span class="checkmark addon_checkbox"></span>
    
  <div class="v-center">None</div>
  </label>
  
  <label :for="'product-'+product.id"
class="is_flex addon_label"
:class="{'addon_selected': selected}"
:data-product-id="product.id"
  >
  <div class="checkbox-container">
<input class=""
  type="checkbox"
  :true-value="true" 
  :false-value="false"
  :id="'product-'+product.id"
  v-model="selected"/>
  <span class="checkmark addon_checkbox"></span>
```

Comment: Web development is not about what you (as a developer) *"like"*. It's about conveying a message in an accessible way, using available conventions. Radio buttons are used for cases where selecting an option deselects all other options in the set.  Checkboxes are for the case where the user can select any number of options. Selecting one does not affect the others. Of course, you can disregard these conventions, if you want, but, in most cases, it also means assistive technologies won't work as expected. Consider learning and using the web standards.

Comment: Very good point. I hadn't really considered the assistive technology aspect. Switched it to radio buttons instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you just need to have two v-models, one for each button, and to create a function that when one of the two buttons changes, each of the values takes its opposite value.

Then, in order to avoid deselection by clicking on its own button, you use `:disabled=` with the reference of your button

**Vue.js 3 with Composition**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

let selectedNone = ref(true);
let selectedChoice = ref(false);

function selectOption() {
  selectedNone.value = !selectedNone;
  selectedChoice.value = !selectedChoice;
}
</script>

<template>
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :value="false"
      v-model="selectedNone"
      :disabled="selectedNone"
      @click="selectOption"
    />
    <span>None</span>
  </label>

  <label >
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="selectedChoice"
        :disabled="selectedChoice"
        @click="selectOption"
      />
      <span>Choice</span>
  </label>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) to check if the value of the checkbox has changed, and then either select all or deselect all, based on that.

Here's a [quick demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-cookies-zr9r3o?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      options: {
        check1: null,
        check2: null,
        check3: null,
      },
      check1: null,
      check2: null,
      check3: null,
      deselect: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    deselect(isDeselected) {
      if (isDeselected) {
        this.options.check1 = false;
        this.options.check2 = false;
        this.options.check3 = false;
      }
    },
    options() {
      console.log("Change");
    },
    ...["options.check1", "options.check2", "options.check3"].reduce(function (
      acc,
      currentKey
    ) {
      acc[currentKey] = function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) this.deselect = false;
      };
      return acc;
    },
    {}),
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label for="check1">Check 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="options.check1" id="check1" />
    <br />
    <label for="check2">Check 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="options.check2" id="check2" />
    <br />
    <label for="check3">Check 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="options.check3" id="check3" />
    <br />
    <label for="deselect-check">Deselect All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="deselect" id="deselect-check" />
</div>
```